# s3cmd put -preserve flag does not preserve file creation /Modified date when copied to s3 bucket

Tags: s3cmd

I am copying files for AWS ec2 to AWS s3 bucket, with --preserver flag to preserver to file create and modified date, but once file is copied to s3bucket, "s3cmd ls s3://bucket-name/" command list the file upload time as file time, it does not preserve the original file creation date-time. I am using following command(s3cmd put --preserve xyz.log s3://bucket-name/) to copy the file.  Though s3cmd help list the --preserve or -p as something you can use to preserve the date it does not seems to be working.

Has anybody run in to this kind of issue and can point me what I am doing wrong.

I also tried s3cmd sync but sync command also behave same way, though I would prefer to use put.

s3cmd put --preserve xyz.log s3://bucket-name/

Thanks,

Comment: Created a bug report: https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/290

Answer (score 2):

Please try the current upstream github.com/s3tools/s3cmd master branch.  This is resolved there.  Going round trip (s3cmd sync --preserve file s3://bucket/; rm file; s3cmd sync --preserve s3://bucket/file .;) now restores the atime and mtime values as stored during sync upload.